# Any place to look for sshd IP address connected TO in logs

Tags: logs, sshd

On a multi-homed system, is there a log which indicates what IP address the clients used when they connected to the local system's ssh server?  This is an "after the fact" question so configuring different IP addresses to use different ports on the ssh server isn't helpful.

For example, let's say a multi-homed system has IP addresses 192.168.0.4 and 172.16.31.4, what I'm looking for is which IP address (of these two) did a road-warrior client at VPN IP address 10.100.100.17 connect to when both IP addresses are equally available to them.

Comment: On what *nix precisely?

Answer (score 0):

Check audit logs under **/var/log/audit** or **/var/log/auth.log** , they will contain entries :

hostname=hostname|ip_addr

addr=ip_addr

Comment: The OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS which uses /var/log/auth.log.  egrep -i "hostname|addr" /var/log/auth.log doesn't return anything.  There are "from" entries but those show the client IP address, not what they connected to.

Comment: what do you mean by showing the client IP addresses not what ghey are connected to ? can you edit your question and make it more clearer with an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in "man ssh", sshd sets several variables for the client, one of which is SSH_CONNECTION.  In order to capture this server side you can use

```
ForceCommand /path/to/a/script
```

in sshd-config.  An example of the script contents could be:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/echo "$SSH_CONNECTION" >> /path/to/documentation/file
case $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND in
     "")
        /bin/bash
        ;;
     *)
        $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
        ;;
esac
```

Notes: 'file' above needs to be group-writable and all ssh users need to be in the group, the "ssh" command itself results in an empty $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND, launch a shell in that situation.